# MySQL File Import

Tags: mysql

I have the below text and am looking to import the data into the a MySQL database, each file being a single record.

I tried mysqlimport, but I think the field names are confusing the import. Is there any way to import the data ignoring the field names. I am making the assumption, that all fields are being imported, leaving no data out. If there are any command line tools, that could help with this or a "open source" tool that can create a script/program that will run the import via a scheduled task (windows) that would be even better.

```
VERS: 355.046
DATE: 2013-01-21
TIME: 15:04:43.242
FILE: C:\Recordings\20130121_150443_242_00_002.WAV
CONN: 8274
STOP: 16595
SIGN: 1601 (0156A70C1300007F)
UNIT: 00
PORT: 002
DIR : 1
CLI : 011*
DDI : 078*
MSGA: 
MSGB: 
MSGC: 
INFO:
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can wrangle this into a format that [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) can handle then you're in much better shape. That's usually not too hard if you have a scripting language you're familiar with.

A standard format might be CSV if you can expect consistent columns.

Comment: Yeah, thinking I may have to. This format is dumped out by call recording hardware. So I'd have to do it post output.